# Converting simple C# statements to pseudocode

Tags: c#

I'm still a C# newbie and trying to fully understand some given code . Can any C# wizards explain or convert the following into 'pseudocode'?

```
_index = (Mathf.Max(0, _index+1))%_filenames.Count;
```

and

```
_movieLoadIndex = (_movieLoadIndex + 1)%2;
```

Comment: C# movie or C# newbie? Autocorrect fail? :)

Comment: [`%`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) operator is the rest of a division and we use them a lot to match pairs, in other words, to know when we have odd/even results, or even to loop throw rows of `n` elements.

Comment: BTW from the [`Mathf.Max`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Max.html) keyword, this seems [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Max.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mathf.Max` takes the largest of 2 numbers, so take the largest between `0` and `index+1` (basically take `index+1`, and make sure it's at least `0`) and modulo it by the count of filenames (modulo takes the remainder of a division, so `10%4 = 2` because `10/4 = 2` and `2` remains)

Same concept for the second line, add `1` to `moveLoadIndex` and take the remainder of it divided by `2`

This looks like code that needs documenting.